# Trouble Reliably Enabling/Disabling MMCSS

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement MMCSS in my project to improve timing performance, and I am seeing odd behavior. I'm a low-level embedded software developer struggling to do software, and this is my first post here, so your patience and understanding is appreciated if my description needs work.

I can't share all my code, but here's some pseudo-code showing how I'm applying MMCSS (taken mostly from the exclusive-mode streams example from MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb614507.aspx):

```
main()
{
    \\ setup/initialize some things

    DWORD taskIndex = 0;
    HANDLE hTask = NULL;

    hTask = AvSetMmThreadCharacteristics(TEXT("Pro Audio"), &taskIndex);
    if (hTask == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        \\ print time since last loop

        \\ do things - some conditions will break out of loop

        \\ sleep
    }

    if (hTask != NULL)
    {
        AvRevertMmThreadCharacteristics(hTask);
    }
}
```

The behavior that I'm seeing is hard to fully characterize. When I run my project, if MMCSS is successfully applied (which it may not be the first few times I run my code), it appears to work reliably the whole time I'm running the exe. If it ran right the previous time, then it will run right every time after that. However, if I comment out the MMCSS code and rebuild and run, it will continue to behave as if MMCSS is applied. I have found that if I restart my computer then run again, I will get timing information indicating MMCSS is no longer being applied.

It seems like I am missing something that is causing the transition from MMCSS enabled to disabled (and vice versa) to be messy. Am I calling the SetMmThreadCharacteristics and RevertMmThreadCharacteristics in the wrong place? Is there some other/additional method(s) I should be calling?